# Substitution cipher that takes key '01234' and substitutes them in the order of the indices (numbers)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not sure on how to get the 'key' and 'num' to work together to get the end answer.
I am thinking using a .replace[] but quite frankly I do not understand the language enough to write this type of code.

Example:

```
encrypt('3924056871', '445566')
```

should return `'005566'`.

```
def encrypt(key, num):
   lst=[]
   for i in key:
     for i in num:
```

Comment: Is this homework? (It is acceptable if it is, it just changes the kind of answers that people can give you).

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways.

1: Using built in `translate` and `maketrans`:

```
from string import maketrans
def encrypt1(key, numstr):
    trans = maketrans('0123456789', key)
    return numstr.translate(trans)
```

2: Manually:

```
def encrypt2(key, numstr):
    res = ""
    for ch in numstr:
        res += key[ord(ch) - ord('0')]
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `key` has 10 characters and plain_text only has digits

```
def enc(key, plain_text):
    """
    >>> enc('3921056784', '445566')
    '005566'
    """
    return ''.join([key[int(x)] for x in plain_text])
```